# How to set up Web Role to A Record DNS

Tags: c#, azure

I have a Web Role with a web application on it and also I have an A Record DNS which im pointing to the IP of my Web Role deployment. I would like to know what should I do now to be able to type mydns.com and then display my Default.aspx form. or well any other form that is the default of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have the majority (if not all) of what is needed.  Sometimes it takes a while for the dns to propagate.  There is a good walk through here on A records: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/

The one thing you many need to do is set the default document in your web.config, which is something like this:

```
<configuration>   
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
     <files>
        <add value="default.aspx" />
     </files>
  </defaultDocument>    
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```